# Solve coupled stochastic differential equations with time-derivatives

Tags: integration, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a stochastic differential equation as $\dot{\alpha}(t)=-a \alpha(t)+b \eta (t)$, where $\overline{\eta(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\eta(t)\eta(t')}=\delta(t-t')$. This is also called an Orstein-Uhlenbeck process. This can formally be integrated to $\alpha(t)=b\int_0^t ds e^{-a (t-s)}\eta(s)$ and one can find its first and second moments or its two-time correlations.

Let's say now that I have another stochastic differential equation that depends now on $\alpha(t)$ and $\dot{\alpha}(t)$

$\dot{x}(t)=(-\gamma+\alpha(t))x(t)+\dot{\alpha}(t)$

and I would like to get the second moments of x(t), i.e. $\overline{x^2(t)}$ (actually the steady-state solution, but it does not matter).

In my previous equation, if I didn't have the $\dot{\alpha}(t)$ term, I could do something like

$\dot{x}(t)=(-\gamma+b \int ds e^{-a (t-s)}\eta(s))x(t)$

and then use Itô rules and then average to get an equation of motion for $\overline{x^2(t)}$. There is, however, the other term with the time-derivative, which I am not quite sure how to proceed.

Is it correct to then say that:

$\dot{x}(t)=(-\gamma+b \int ds e^{-a (t-s)}\eta(s))x(t)-a \alpha(t)+b \eta (t)=(-\gamma+b \int ds e^{-a (t-s)}\eta(s))x(t)-a b \int ds e^{-a (t-s)}\eta(s)+b \eta (t)$

Am I doing something wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment)

A little detail to begin with : you forgot a term in the solution for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process; indeed, it should be $\alpha(t) = \alpha(0)e^{-at} + b\int_0^t e^{-a(t-s)}\eta(s) \mathrm{d}s$, unless the initial condition is $\alpha(0) = 0$ of course.

From $\dot{x} = \dot{\alpha} + (\alpha-\gamma)x = -(\gamma+(a-1)\alpha)x + b\eta$, you can apply Itô's lemma to the quantity $x^2$, before taking the average and solving the differential equation - actually, you'll see that you need to determine $\langle x \rangle$ in the first place in order to solve it.

However, such computations might reveal themselves quite tedious in physicists' style, that is why I would advise you to carry them within the formalism of stochastic calculus, whose notation has the advantage to be more concise, particularly when dealing with Itô's lemma. Practically, you can switch between them with the help of the convention $\eta(t) = \dot{B}_t \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{d}B_t = \eta(t)\mathrm{d}t$, so that the equation of motion of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process becomes $\mathrm{d}\alpha_t = -a\alpha_t\mathrm{d}t + b\,\mathrm{d}B_t$ for instance.